# Change Derby DB password

Tags: derby, change-password

I have already set a Derby DB password in Glassfish/Netbeans. I also checked the remember me checkbox.

Now I cannot change the password anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change the password you only have to execute:

```
call SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.user.<my user name>', '<your new password>')
```

for example if you username is 'john' and you want you new password to be 'johnsnewpassword' you would call:

```
call SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY('derby.user.john', 'johnsnewpassword')
```

Answer (score 3):

Call

```
SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_RESET_PASSWORD('userid', 'newpassword');
```

See [Built-in system procedures/ SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_RESET_PASSWORD in Java DB Reference Manual](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/ref/rrefnativeresetpasswordproc.html).

Comment: This is the better answer because the scope is narrower. Giving a user permission to execute the `RESET_PASSWORD` command gives the user less potential to wreak havoc than giving them permission to execute the `SET_DATABASE_PROPERTY` command.