# Netbeans derby database, forgoten password ot connect,

Tags: netbeans, derby

I have to make school project in netbeans, we have to use derby database, but sadly i forgot username and password from past session. Is there any way to recover those or do i have to start from start.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Derby DB password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004297/change-derby-db-password)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i found the answer, if you look into log/log1.dat, you can search for derby.user, following that it should be your username, password is writen in there too, but there isn't anything that you could search for.